# imagepng in combination with include does not work anymore

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, include, php-5.6

Why does this script not work anymore? The script has been working with previous php versions (before 5.6) and default encoding for the database connection:

```
include('connect-to-database-with-utf8.php');

header('Content-Type: image/png');    
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(45, 22);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagestring($im, 10, 5, 3, '1234', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

The webbrowser says that the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors... But if I don't use any includes by copying the code into file directly, it will work. Very strange.

The include file 'connect-to-database-with-utf8.php' contains:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_password');  
$mysqli->select_db('db_name');

// set charset to utf-8 for database requests
$mysqli->set_charset('utf-8');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SET CHARACTER SET \'utf8\'');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Does `connect-to-database-with-utf8.php` page perhaps have a space before the `<?php` and if you have a `?>` at the end of the file, maybe there is a space after that?

Comment: @Rasclatt sry, but that's not the issue...

Comment: Enable error reporting (always when developing & testing code). `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the code, and see what you get when you comment out `// imagepng($im)`.  There's quite possibly some error/notice output breaking the image output.

Comment: no errors regarding to the issue, sry